# Visual Studio 2019 and EXCEL Addin .xll debug and Office 365 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2019, excel-addins, xll

We develop .xlls (Essentially an Excel Extension in C++) in C++ (Visual studio 2019). We typically debug these by configuring the Debug environment in the properties for the project. We typically set the command to be run as /excel.exe /X  and debug the xll code.

This worked fine till we started transition to OFFICE 365. The excel is a 64 bit version. That is really not a problem. We have built appropriate 64 bit xlls. The issue is that Visual  Studio fails to launch EXCEL. We see an error "<...>/excel.exe exited with code -1" and a dialog that says could not launch excel.

What has changed? Do folks have similar experience and how have they resolved the issue. The work around is to launch excel from a batch file and attach from visual studio. However this is too tedious.

Thanks in advance for the assistance and help.

Comment: Is your addin being loaded automatically, or do you manually load in Excel once Excel is up & running? Also, you could try adding the `/automation` flag: this stops Excel loading any addins at startup, and can be handy for trouble-shooting.

Comment: @DS_London It was the way the command was configured to run. We figured it out. I had quotes around the command. I am unable to understand why the quote is not necessary. The 32-bit excel is under "Program Files (X86)" and he office 365 version is under "Program Files". My understanding was that you needed to quote the command if there were spaces in the path to the file. I guess I was wrong. The 32-bit excel requires you to quote the command. It maybe doe to the parenthesis. I am not sure.

Comment: If you go into the Debugging properties for the project, and click on the entry field for Command, and then on the drop-down arrow, you can Browse for the executable. That will create the full pathname for you.

Comment: @DS_London we usually do not have that kind of discipline, we copy paste and modify the path and get in trouble. LOL!!!